# Continuously update h5 tag text based on new div's data attr when scrolled into view

Tags: jquery, html, function, text, attributes

I want to continuously update h5 tag text based on current div's data attr when scrolled into view. CSS is set up where the .bar class takes up 100% height and only one is in view at a time. I am able to pass the first image title to the h5 tag but it will not update when a new .bar div is scrolled into view.

HTML

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="bar" >
        <img class="image" id="i_003" data-title="title_3" src="path/here_3.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="bar" >
        <img class="image" id="i_002" data-title="title_2" src="path/here_2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="bar" >
        <img class="image" id="i_001" data-title="title_1" src="path/here_1.jpg">
    </div>  
</div>

<div id="img_info">
    <h5 id="title">title here</h5>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#foo').scroll(function() {
    var imgTitle = $('.image').attr('data-title');

    $("#title").text(imgTitle);

    console.log("imgTitle: " + imgTitle);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uokfcvvx/)

Get the position of each .bar within its container in a variable such as an array. Analize the scrollTop position of the container when it is scrolled and compare its value to the top values fro the variable. When the scrollTop value is in between one of the .bar then apply its image data-title value.

(As you didn't provide CSS I made some fast one, I hope it matches your case)

```js
var $foo = $('#foo'),
  $title = $('#title'),
  $bar = $('div.bar'),
  $img = $bar.find('img.image');

img_top = [$img.eq(0).offset().top, $img.eq(1).offset().top, $img.eq(2).offset().top];

$foo.on('scroll', function(e) {

  var scrolltop = $foo.scrollTop();

  if (scrolltop > img_top[2]) {
    $title.text($img.eq(2).data('title'));
  } else if (scrolltop > img_top[1]) {
    $title.text($img.eq(1).data('title'));
  } else if (scrolltop > img_top[0]) {
    $title.text($img.eq(0).data('title'));
  } else if (scrolltop < img_top[0]) {
    $title.text('this could be the default?');
  }

});
```

```css
.bar {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#img_info {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#foo {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <img class="image" id="i_003" data-title="title_3" src="path/here_3.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="bar">
    <img class="image" id="i_002" data-title="title_2" src="path/here_2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="bar">
    <img class="image" id="i_001" data-title="title_1" src="path/here_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="img_info">
  <h5 id="title">title here</h5>
</div>
```